# Specify input() type in Python?

Tags: python, input, types

Is it possible to define input times, like time, date, currency or that should be verified manually? Like for example:

```
morning = input('Enter morning Time:')
evening = input('Enter evening Time:')
```

.. I need (only) time here, how do I make sure that user enters input in xx:xx format where xx are integers only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) (in Python 2.any) will return the type of whatever expression the user types in.  Better (in Python 2.any) is to use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input), which returns a string, and do the conversion yourself, catching the `TypeError` if the conversion fails.

Python 3.any's `input` works like 2.any's `raw_input`, i.e., it returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really force the `input` function to return a certain type. It's best you write some kind of a wrapper that reads some input from the user and then converts it to an appropriate type for your application (or throw an exception in case of an error).

Also, as Alex said, it's better to use `raw_input` for user input since it will always return the entered value as a string. Much more manageable.