# python convert a string to a integer for multiplication

Tags: python

I realise that this is probably simple and basic to you guys, its for my childs homework and I don't have any experience or idea on the use of Python. She needs to get the code to request a number, multiply it by 9 and show the result. She is using the code below, however it repeats the number rather than multiply it. (ie it show 3 * 9 as 999 instead of 27). From what I have read it appears this is something to with multiplying integer by strings (though I may be wrong). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
number=input("Enter a number to multiply by 9 ")
number=number*9
print('the answer is '+number)
```

Comment: Can you share the version of python you are using to run this code ?

Comment: Thats because number is a string here, multiplying a string just concatenates it

Comment: print('the answer is '+str(number)), input does the conversion to int. Anyways its int(val) or float(val) for decimals

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800846/differences-between-input-and-raw-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `input` in either [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) or [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float)

```
number=int(input("Enter a number to multiply by 9 "))
```

or

```
number=float(input("Enter a number to multiply by 9 "))
```

This is done because [`input`](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html#numbers-and-strings-of-digits) accepts strings and you have to convert these to numerals.

Comment: input doesn't accept strings, i mean if you enter 10 it accepts it as an integer itself.

Comment: @Alfie, for Python 2, that is correct. For Python 3, that is not. (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964996/specify-input-type-in-python) ). I assumed Python 3 based on the `print` function utilized.