# Why am I receiving a Type error for this input function

Tags: python, function, input, spyder

I am trying to write a program that requests the number
of seconds between lightning and thunder and reports the distance from the storm
rounded to two decimal places.

```
n = input('Enter the number of seconds between lightning and storm') 
1.25
print('Distance from storm',n/5)
```

However, when I call the print function, I receive the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<ipython-input-106-86c5a1884a8d>", line 1, in <module>
     print('Distance from storm',n/5)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: `print('Distance from storm',int(n)/5)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify input() type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964996/specify-input-type-in-python)

Comment: You can also check if input as in other similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the input as in **int** or **float** and then proceed with further operations.

```
n = int(input('Enter the number of seconds between lightning and storm   '))
Enter the number of seconds between lightning and storm   99

print('Distance from storm',n/5)
```

OutPut:

```
('Distance from storm', 19)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert your `n` to a `int` or a `float` (which ever suits your requirement) since it is a `string`:

The `input()` function returns a string, and therefore you cannot apply the division, hence the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

So you need to convert it:

```
n = input('Enter the number of seconds between lightning and storm')
1.25
print('Distance from storm',int(n)/5)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Distance from storm 8.6
```

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be cast to a float seeing as it's 1.25?

Comment: @RoelvanEndhoven That depend what OP needs.

Comment: I still receive an error:In [109]: print('Distance from storm',int(n)/5)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-109-cc4183133c07>", line 1, in <module>
    print('Distance from storm',int(n)/5)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.25'